# Mongoose: uniqueness across several fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, express, mongoose

Here's my schema:

```
var user = new Schema({
  // other fields...

  email_1: String,
  email_2: String
});
```

Is there a way to ensure uniqueness of both *email_1* and *email_2* ? Ie., if some email is saved as *email_1* of one user, it can not be saved as *email_1* or *email_2* by anyone else.

I've tried compound index, but it only checks for email pairs, and I need all emails to be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that arrays are indexed as [multikey indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/) and store your emails as an "ordered pair" `[email1, email2]`:

```
> db.emails.ensureIndex({ "emails" : 1 }, { "unique" : true })
> db.emails.insert({ "emails" : ["me@wdb.com", "metoo@wdb.com"] })
> db.emails.insert({ "emails" : ["you@eagor.com", "me@wdb.com"] }) // MongoDB says NO!
> db.emails.insert({ "emails" : ["metoo@wdb.com", "myself@wdb.com"] }) // MongoDB says NO
```

Comment: thank you. works good on new database, but not on my old one. Do I need to somehow reensure/reset/drop the indexes on the database?